# SQLite identify long value

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to identify SQLite column data types and I do not know how to check if the number in column is `long` or `int` or also if the number is `float` or `double`.

```
Cursor c;
Object val;
int type = c.getType(i);
if(type == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB){
    val = c.getBlob(i);
}else if(type == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT){
    val = c.getFloat(i);
}else if(type == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER){
    val = c.getInt(i);
}else if(type == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_LONG){ //this here is the problem. "Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_LONG" does not exists
    val = c.getLong(i);
} else if(type == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL){
    val = null;
}else if(type == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING){
    val = c.getString(i);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to reverse engineer the database someone else developed?

Comment: There's no **LONG** in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. Problem solved.

Comment: @StG: I am trying to write "universal" query function so that I wont have to deal with looping through `Cursor` for every query.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has no column data types; values in a column can have different types.

As the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storageclasses) shows, integers can be stored in 8 bytes, so if you don't know how large the values in the column actually are, you must use `getLong`.

Floats also are 8-byte values, so you must use `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Tnx for answers.

> SQLite has no column data types; values in a column can have different types.

After a bit of testing a found that `Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER` matches both, int and long and that `Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT` matches float and double.

**So this code does the job for me:**

```
//...
if(type == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT){
    float floatVal = c.getFloat(i);
    double doubleVal = c.getDouble(i);
    if(floatVal == doubleVal) val = floatVal;
    else val = doubleVal;
}else if(type == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER){
    int intVal = c.getInt(i);
    long longVal = c.getLong(i);
    if(intVal == longVal) val = intVal;
    else val = longVal;
}
//...
```